# Sequence of Semisimple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem I am working on can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145572/hint-needed-on-measure-theory-question-approximation-by-semisimple-functions). In this MSE post, drhab and Fnacool provide hints which suggest two entirely different approaches. I have come up with two solutions based upon each hint, and I am hoping that someone would critique them. Here is the first solution, based up on drhab's hint:

> Let $f : E \to \Bbb{R}$ be some measurable function. For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, define $f_n : E \to \Bbb{R}$ by $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} [nf(x)]$. Clearly this is a semisimple function since its range is some subset of $\Bbb{Q}$, whose countability is well-known. Moreover, $f_n$ certainly converges to $f$ uniformly, since $|nf(x) - [nf(x)]| < 1 \le n$ holds for all $x \in E$, as the quantity in the absolute value bars is just the fractional part of $nf(x)$, and therefore dividing by $n$ gives $|f(x) - \frac{1}{n} [nf(x)]| < \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $x \in E$. Hence $f_n \to f$ uniformly

The only problem I see is that $f$'s measurability doesn't appear to be used anywhere. Also, drhab claims that, not only are the $f_n$ semisimple, but they are measurable. This, I imagine, is where $f$'s measurability becomes. I could use a hint on showing that $f_n$ is measurable.

Here is the second solution.

> Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$, and define 
>   $$E_{n,k} = \{x \mid f(x) \in [\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n})\} = f^{-1}([\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}))$$ 
>   for every $k \in \Bbb{Z}$. Note that for $x \in \Bbb{R}$, there exists an integer $k$ so that $k \le 2^{-n}x < k+1$, which proves that $\Bbb{R} = \bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} [\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n})$, and therefore
>   $$\bigcup_{k \in\Bbb{Z}} E_{n,k} = \bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} f^{-1}([\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}))= f^{-1}(\bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{Z}}[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n})) = f^{-1}(\Bbb{R}) = E$$
>   That the $E_{n,k}$ form a partition of $E$ follows from the more general fact that $a \in [p,p+1) \cap [q,q+1)$ implies $p=q$. Hence, for every $x \in E$, there exists some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $0 \le f(x) - \frac{k}{2^n} < \frac{1}{2^n}$. Defining $f_n(x) = \frac{k}{2^n}$, we see that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$ hold for every $x \in E$, which proves that $f_n \to f$ uniformly

As with the first solution, I don't see where measurability was used, if at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be defined by $f_n(x)=\frac1{n}\lfloor nf(x)\rfloor$

Then the image of $f_n$ is a subset of $\left\{\frac{k}{n}\mid k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$.

So for the preimage of some set $B$ we find:

$$f_n^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}^{\infty}f_n^{-1}\left(B\cap\left\{\frac{k}{n}\right\}\right)=\bigcup_{k\in I_B}f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right)\right)$$

where $I_B:=\left\{k\in\mathbb Z\mid \frac{k}{n}\in B\right\}$.

$I_B$ is countable and **the measurability of** $f$ guarantees that set $f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}\right)\right)$ is measurable for every $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Then as a union of measurable sets $f_n^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

This for *every* set $B\subseteq \mathbb R$ so $f_n$ will be measurable.

Comment: Wow! This is brilliant! You certainly deserve more upvotes on the answer you provided to linked question, as well as many on this! That the preimage of every subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is measurable is a striking property. Are there anymore functions with it; does such a class of functions have a name?

Comment: By the way, if you have a chance, would you mind taking a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479085/borel-measurable-functions-and-a-certain-collection-of-borel-sets I haven't had any bites yet.

Comment: At least all functions that have a countable image and next to that have measurable fibers have this property. I don't know a name for the class. Actually you could say that all measurable functions that have a countable image have the property since their fibers must be measurable.